# Php.ini file structure in cpanel is different

Tags: php, apache, ldap, cpanel

I have a php file that authenticate with ldap, it was working fine on localhost but when i uploaded it to cpanel(softaculous), i got this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect(), i know that i have to uncomment `extension=php_ldap.dll` in `php.ini`, i opened the `php.ini` and i didn't found `extension=php_ldap.dll` & i found that its structure is different from the one on my PC, how can i solve this problem?

```
allow_url_fopen = Off
allow_url_include = Off
asp_tags = Off
display_errors = On
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = 32M
session.save_path = ""
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

Comment: Do you have access to WHM? If so, you have to enable 'mod_ldap' through EasyApache (Home >> Software >> EasyApache 3/4).

Comment: What easyapache version are you running? 3 or 4?

Comment: @RoseHosting, I enabled `mod_ldap` in EasyApache 4,but when i enable `php56-php-ldap` my website stop working,do you know why?